# Standard PriceBook is not available for adding to an Opportunity

Tags: apex

I am trying to add standard price book in opportunities. but i cannot find standard price book in Choose Price Book for picklist.

What should be the problem?

Comment: Is the price book active?

Comment: yeah that was the issue. thx.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the pricebook is activated

Answer (score 0):

Got it, pricebook was not activated.

Comment: please mark or upvote Eric answer as it answered your query .Please delete your own as it speaks same as Eric answer